# passing a Url.Action to a react JSX file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

[This tutorial](https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial_aspnet4.html) says:

> Note that in a real app, you should generate the URL server-side (via Url.Action call) and pass it down, or use RouteJs rather than hard-coding it. This tutorial hard-codes it for simplicity.

I can't do this in the JS itself:
`<CommentBox url="@Url.Action("Comments")" />,`

... so what does it mean by "pass it down"?

Is that just another way of saying "define the URL inside a Razor csHtml file where using `@` is allowed," like this?

```
<script>
   $.CommentsUrl = '@this.Url.Action("Comments", "Home")';
<script>
```

... or is there a better way?

Even when I do the latter, that doesn't help me get the URL into this piece of code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox url=??? />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is actually done in the cshtml razor page. It is rendering the CommentBox component to the content div

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox url=??? />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Since it is in the cshtml you can do this:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ReactDOM.render(
        <CommentBox url='@Url.Action("Comments")' />,
        document.getElementById('content')
    );
</script>
```

If you are only including a js file then you would need to create a global javascript variable and use it:

CSHTML:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var commentUrl = '@Url.Action("Comments")';
</script>
```

External JS:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox url={commentUrl} />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: I'm putting the JS in a JSX file - Is it possible to get a variable assigned to the `url` attribute of `CommentBox` ?

Comment: Edited my answer. Make sure the script tag in the cshtml comes before any of your react components.

Comment: Awesome! didn't realize the curly braces could do that. Thanks

Comment: @Matt It is possible to do it with different projects? somehing like, in reactjs project call a cshtml file from a mvc project

Comment: React isnt calling a CSHTML file. The CSHTML file loads the url as a prop that is passed to the React Component. In this example the CSHTML is loading the react component. You cant have react load a CSHTML file, however you can call the url for you view from anywhere. What are you trying to accomplish @CatarinaBatista?

Comment: @Matt I have a web app (that wasn't me that did it, and I think that was done in mvc ) and I'm doing a "new face" of that app, a navbar and side bar, and in the middle it suposed to appear that cshtml file

Comment: @Matt and that cshtml file is from mvc app, and I don't know how to put them together, I dont know if it suposed to modify the cshtml file or if it is possible to load that file in react or if exists another way simpler...